# Orders Not Showing Under Customer's "My Orders" Tab

Tags: magento-1, frontend

Some Customers are able to see their past orders under the "My Orders" Tab and some are not. I was able to narrow it down to just customers who have a custom attribute attached to their account but I am unsure why just they would be able to see their order history.

If you are signed in under customers who cannot see their past orders it does show "recently ordered" in the bottom left corner but will not give them the full total and order, only allow them to check the boxes next to the items to order again.

Have anyone else seen this happen?

Comment: Certain order statues result in orders which are hidden from the frontend. It's all configurable. Have you looked into statuses.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I did test quite a few different statuses for both customer groups. All orders submitted regardless of status for the custom attribute customers showed up but none of the orders for customers without showed up in their frontend unfortunately.